# Why won't click events work on a span but the will work on an a?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone think of a reason why a click event would work on an `a` tag, but not on a `span`? I am making a rich text editor and have a bold button that when clicked is supposed to make the text bold. It only works when I use an anchor element. I tried using a span and nothing happens. The html is the only thing that I am changing so I don't think it is a JavaScript problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//creates the toolbar~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  $('#rte').focus()

  var tools = [];
  tools.push('underline');
  tools.push('italic');
  tools.push('bold');
  tools.push('justifyCenter');
  tools.push('justifyLeft');
  tools.push('justifyRight');

  var simple_toolbar = function(){
  //iterates through each tool and adds its functionality to the editor
  $.each(tools, function(index,value){ 
      $('#'+value).click(function(event){
        document.execCommand( value, false, null);
        $('#rte').focus();
        return false;
      });
      //end of click function
  });
    //end of each iterator  

  };
  //end of simple toolbar function

  //invokes the simple toolbar.
  simple_toolbar();
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



});
//end of the DOM loader
```

---

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>An HTML5 page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="controls">
        <!-- The only button working here is the bold because it is an <a> --> 
        <a href="#" id="bold"></a>
        <span id="italic"></span>
        <span id="underline"></span>
        <span id="justifyLeft"></span>
        <span id="justifyCenter"></span>
        <span id="justifyRight"></span>   
      </div><!--end of controlls div-->

      <div contenteditable="true" id="rte"></div>

      <textarea id="my_form" rows="8" cols="58" ></textarea>
  </div><!--end of the wrapper div-->

  </body>

</html>
```

---

```
#bold{
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25006518/bold.png');

}

#italic{
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25006518/italic.png');

}

#underline{
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25006518/underline.png');

}

#justifyCenter{
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25006518/underline.png');

}

#justifyRight{
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25006518/underline.png');

}

#justifyRight{
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25006518/underline.png');

}
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Have you tried floating or setting display: block on the span to see if that makes a difference?
If the span is empty that might be a solution.

Comment: The span element can be bound to all the common event handlers so it's probably a JavaScript problem. Can you expose some code?

Comment: dose the span have its width and height set, and dose it have a display like inline-block?

Comment: Yes. the span has width, height, and diplay block.

Comment: I think I am just going to stick with the anchor tags. I was just curious why changing the type of tag would make it mess up. Thanks for taking a look though.

Comment: On Chrome, the anchor tag does not make the selection get lost, whereas the span tag does. I've no idea why though. The justifying does work when you focus before calling `execCommand` by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/UR5QG/.

Comment: Try cancelling the mousedown event (when clicking on the span), this should prevent the focus from being lost when clicking. Maybe it will help. http://jsfiddle.net/UR5QG/1/ works, see my answer.

Comment: Your click event is working properly on span, you can debug or put alert inside your click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best solution, but the only reason I wanted to use spans is so that the page would not jump to the top when you clicked an anchor tag with an `href="#"`. I decided to just use the anchor tags, but instead of using `href="#"` I am using `href="#bold"`. apparently when you use an id selector as an href attribute the page will jump to the spot on the page where that element is. Still not sure why it won't work with other elements. I tried just getting rid of the iterator and writing out a separate click event for each button, but it still only worked with an anchor tag.

Comment: You can use anchors with href="javascript:void(0)" and no jumps will happen

Comment: You could also return false from a link's click handler to avoid jumping, although it sounds like the normal named anchor is fine. Moin's comment also works.

Comment: You should mark this, or anyone else's answer as the accepted answer, if it solved your problem. It's the `✓` (tick) symbol.

Answer (score 3):

if you update your jQuery to v1.7.1 you can use the .on() function. This will then allow you to bind the click method to the span using an id.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#yourContainer").on("click", "#yourSpanID", function(){
      // The code to make everything bold
   });
});
```

Comment: I haven't seen API docs for this. Why would one use the "on" method instead of the "bind" method? An "on" method sounds a bit redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Any DOM element can listen for a "click" event, and in fact the code as you presented it is working in that sense. If you precede your call to document.execCommand with an alert statement you'll find that the alert occurs anytime you click on any of the buttons and not just the "bold" button.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your span tags the wrong way; span tags are for coloring and styling one word in a sentence.

The best thing to do is use the `<ul>` tag; you do have to end it. Like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<ul>

<li><a href="put a link file here if you want">"put your text here"</a></li>
<li><a href="put a link file here if you want">"put your text here"</a></li>
<li><a href="put a link file here if you want">"put your text here"</a></li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Now assuming you have a style sheet you can style the  or user list in CSS
like this:

```
html{  }
body{  }

ul{  }
ul li{ float:left; this will define how the tags are displayed }
ul li a{ "from here down define how links act." }
ul li a:visited{ color:put a color here like light blue or something;}
ul li a:hover{ color:same with this; }
ul li a:active{color:same with this; }
```

Also check your hierarchy it will help you in the long run. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable 'value' gets destroyed when the iteration is done. You could make a global function that takes care of the actual click handle and assign this function to the buttons in an iteration.

You could grab the ID of the button clicked in the global function and use that to parse as an argument in the execCommand method.

So it's a scope issue, to be clear.

Comment: I thought this may be the problem too, so I got rid of the fancy iterator and tried just writing a plain old click event for each button. It still only worked with the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the spans to `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to research the 'onclick' event more deeply, but one of two things present:
1) onclick is reserved for 'a' and 'input' tags, only (will set out to verify this); or,
2) a more complex method is required on the event handler. See, W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes

Side Note: Having settled on 'a', one could reduce the style sheet to just background URL on the 'id', and add a descendent selector on the controls:

```
#controls a {
 display: block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Point 1 might not be correct. The page you linked gives `<body onlick="...">` as an example.

Comment: Any DOM element can listen for a click event. It's tough to answer this without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a mousedown event to the span, which you cancel, then span also works. Don't know which (if at all) spec defines different behavior on spans and anchors, but it works now.
See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UR5QG/1/). Changed the following part:

```
$('#'+value).click(function(event){
    document.execCommand( value, false, null);
    $('#rte').focus();
    return false;
}).mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click event you should use either [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
This will bind the click event to all elements even though they are dynamically created.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, use the Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

and then, for the CSS of a span, use:

```
span{
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell why you are suggesting a different doctype, the html 5 doctype is strict enough. Is there any other reason besides your doctype being strict?